# material not applying

Tags: texturing, materials, uv, node-editor

I have my material nodes set up, however, the viewport is not showing any changes.

my nodes were set up like this:

[image]

and the viewport is displaying:

[image]

i wonder how to fix it.

Comment: please provide blend file

Comment: This looks CORRECT to me. The transparent node only lets red light through, so cyan light is reflected back at the camera. I might try changing this whole setup to either a Transluscent BSDF, or a Principled BSDF and turning on subsurface scattering.

Comment: I’m sorry, I’m looking at this with night shade thingy on. Regardless, your node setup only has one tiny color property in the transparent node, limited by fresnel, with white on white with the other two nodes.

Comment: I guess change the render engine to cycle and select rendered by holding Z key.

Comment: Looking at your node setup, your _Transparent_ node is quite a dark red which doesn't bring much color to it, and the _Density_ of the _Volume Absorption_ is set to 204.8 (!). This hardly lets any light through... values of 0.1 to 1 or may even 2 might work, but over 200? And the _Material Preview_ doesn't work well with transparencies and volumes. Maybe switch to _Rendered View_.